# The new array isn't rerendered in the DOM

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

After deleting the todo list item the console shows that the propriete task is deleted but the list isn't rerendered and the deleted todo is still in the list. When the list should be rerendered via getTasks the whole list stays the same. Maybe the ids of the delete method and create a new todo method do not correspond I can't understand.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-bootstrap-vue-dynamic-img-bkwixg?file=pages%2Findex.vue,store%2Findex.js,components%2FTask.vue

```js
// Child component

<template>
    <p class="content">
      {{ task.todo }}
    </p>
      </button>
      <button @click="() => deleteTask(task.id)" class="delete">Delete</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  props: ['task'],
  methods: {
    deleteTask(id) {
      this.$store.dispatch('deleteTask', id);
    },
  },
};
</script>

// Parent component

<template>
  <Task v-for="task in tasks" :key="task.id" :task="task" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    tasks() {
      return this.$store.getters.getTasks;
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch('getTasks').then((data) => console.log(this.tasks));
  },
};
</script>

/// Store

export const state = () => ({
  tasks: [],
});

export const actions = {
  async getTasks(context) {
    const res = await fetch('https://dummyjson.com/todos/user/5');
    if (res.ok) {
      let result = await res.json();
      context.commit('setTasks', result.todos);
    }
    return res.ok;
  },
  async deleteTask(context, id) {
    const res = await fetch(`https://dummyjson.com/todos/${id}`, {
      method: 'DELETE',
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(console.log);
    if (res) {
      let result = await res.json();
      console.log(result);
      context.dispatch('getTasks');
    }
    return res;
  },
};

export const mutations = {
  setTasks(state, data) {
    state.tasks = data;
  },
};

export const getters = {
  getTasks(state) {
    return state.tasks;
  },
};
```

Comment: And the userId do not correspond either